# jclouds putBlob error with B2 - Cache-Control header is not supported or allowed

Tags: jclouds

I've just created a b2 bucket and trying to upload a file using jclouds.

```
PayloadBlobBuilder blobBuilder = blobStore.blobBuilder(remoteFileName)
        .payload(payload)
        .contentLength(payload.size());

Blob blob = blobBuilder.build();

String eTag = blobStore.putBlob(containerName, blob);
```

I get exception details as below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache-Control header is not supported or allowed
    at org.jclouds.b2.handlers.ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.refineException(ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.b2.handlers.ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.handleError(ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.java:58)
    at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError(DelegatingErrorHandler.java:65)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.shouldContinue(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:138)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:107)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:74)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy402.uploadFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.b2.blobstore.B2BlobStore.putBlob(B2BlobStore.java:242)
    at org.jclouds.b2.blobstore.B2BlobStore.putBlob(B2BlobStore.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:37)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy387.putBlob(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.jclouds.b2.B2ResponseException: request POST https://pod-000-1094-01.backblaze.com/b2api/v1/b2_upload_file/xxxx/c002_v0001094_t0008 HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400, error: B2Error{code=bad_request, message=Cache-Control header is not supported or allowed, status=400}
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The B2 service emits this error and [documents Cache-Control](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_upload_file.html) as not supported:

> The following HTTP headers must not be included in the b2_upload_file request:
>
> - Cache-Control

Comment: Could you indicate a code snippet that can be used to upload a file to B2 using jclouds? Is there something in the code snippet in the question that I need to remove or add?

Comment: How did you configure jclouds, e.g., modules?  Do you use the default HTTP client or another?

Comment: I believe I used the bare minimum/default/sample code, so likely using the default http client. I was using the slf4j module for logging. However, the same code that was not working before is working now. Perhaps b2 changed something on their end. I posted an update on the jclouds issue tracker - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1416